# How to change code of struts tag into spring or jstl tag?

Tags: jsp, jstl, struts, struts-1, spring-el

```
<bean:define id="user" name="form" property="user2" type="document.result"  />
```

This is the example of my code.
I was trying to convert my struts code into spring or jstl tag.

I tried converting this

```
<c:set var="user" value="${form.user2}" type="document.result" />
```

But the result shows no type attribute specific by set in JSTL.

Can anyone help me out,how to change it?

Comment: What is the reason to convert old struts tag to the different tag?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `type` attribute

```
<c:set var="user" value="${form.user2}"/>
```

If you use  [`spring-tld`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-tld.html) in the view you can also use SpEL expression.

```
<spring:eval var="user" expression="form.user2"/>
```